# What the simplest way to get object from s3 with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

What the simplest way to get object from s3?

I'm trying, but I'm getting the this message: Promise { pending }

```
class S3Utils {
    static getFile(params) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
                if (!err) {
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

let file = S3Utils.getFile(params);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Async function always returns promise `let file = await S3Utils.getFile(params);`

Comment: @bato3 then he will get `undefined` as result

Comment: thanks @ponury-kostek, also `return await s3.getObject(params,`

Comment: @bato3 this change nothing, still `undefined`

Comment: You need to wrap `s3.getObject` with `Promise` and use `resolve` instead of `return`, and there is no need to use `async/await`

Comment: Nooo!!!!1111 one one one.... This is an extremely "interesting" code. I did not notice so many things. There is also no `then` there XD